# K fold Cross Validation for binomial GLMER model

Tags: r, cross-validation, glm

I am trying to perform a K-fold cross-validation for my predictive GLMER model. It looks like the model structure below. But I can't seem to find one that will take glmer and allow for the use of mixed random effects. I'm trying to predict a binary outcome (1 or 0), mainly the 1s.

```
glmer(A ~ b + c + d + (1|ID)
```

Any ideas? I've used the caret package and the train/traincontrol commands, but those do not allow for glmer, only glm, performance package is restricted to lmer and not glmer.

The caret package and its train/control k fold validations are what I'm hoping to get an output similar to; just simply need one that can handle glmer as well.